# COleBusyDialog customization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I would like to customize `COleBusyDialog` dialog before I call DoModal on it. I am fine with buttons and layout. However I would like to have different static text inside it. How can I change it?
I see it has public member `COleBusyDialog::m_bz` which is used to customize it:

```
typedef struct tagOLEUIBUSY 
{
  DWORD         cbStruct;
  DWORD         dwFlags;
  HWND          hWndOwner;
  LPCTSTR       lpszCaption;
  LPFNOLEUIHOOK lpfnHook;
  LPARAM        lCustData;
  HINSTANCE     hInstance;
  LPCTSTR       lpszTemplate;
  HRSRC         hResource;
  HTASK         hTask;
  HWND          *lphWndDialog;
} OLEUIBUSY, *POLEUIBUSY, *LPOLEUIBUSY;
```

I am new to mfc and I don't know if i have to create new dialog in resources and assign it to this struct or is there simple way to modify the text.

[image: COleBusyDialog]

Answer (score 2):

Derive from COleMessageFilter and overide OnBusyDialog. To use your customized message filter, replace AfxGetThread()->m_pMessageFilter. Then delete the previous message filter and call Register() on the new one.

Comment: So this is what I have already had before. I have created class that derives from messgeFilter and implemented virtual function OnBusyDialog.
And i want to implement it same way however wih customizing COleBusyDialog. It doesn't have any virtual functions that i could use for that. I thought that i can change COleBusyDialog::m_bz after object is created but before doModal() call.

Comment: Here is default implementation from mfc:
'code' int COleMessageFilter::OnBusyDialog(HTASK htaskBusy)
{
 COleBusyDialog dlg(htaskBusy, FALSE);

 int nResult = -1;
 TRY
 {
  if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
   nResult = dlg.GetSelectionType();
 }
 END_TRY

 return nResult;
}
'code'

Comment: >I thought that i can change COleBusyDialog::m_bz after object is created but before doModal() call. what is stopping you?

Comment: I can change this struct to pass new caption or disable some of buttons and it works. However I don't understand how can I pass my own dialog template that I created in resources. Which members do I need to fill to make it work correctly? I usually just create CDialog an pass ID from resources to construct it. I am also not sure what if that COleBusyDialog triggers some events when buttons were pressed and how to handle it. In new dialog I have my own buttons so what about original buttons?

Comment: I was able to use this struct to pass my own dialog. I also had to implement hook function that will catch messages related to clicking new buttons and assign it to lpfnHook member. Now It works same way as previously but I can fully customize the dialog.